# Fastest way to query a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make aggregation operations (sum) on the rows of a big pandas dataframe(millions of rows) which are determined by a condition on several fixed columns (max 10 columns). These columns have only integer values.

My problem is that I have to make this operation (querying + aggregating) thousands of times (~100 000 times). I think with the aggregating part there is not much to optimize as it is just a simple sum. What would be the most efficient way to perform this task? Is there some way I could build an 'index' on my condition columns in order to speed up each query?

Comment: Not that I'm an expert, but  could you post some code about the conditions? Are you using the short-circuiting `all()` or `and`? Can you use arithmetic operations to test simultaneously for a few conditions?

Comment: You should time the ops and see what is actually taking the time. (e.g. use ``%prun/%timeit`` in ipython). A lot of the operations in pandas use ``numexpr`` under the hood so the indexing can be pretty fast.

Comment: Their are several new features in 0.13 (0.13rc1 is out), that you may find useful: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval-experimental; you could also try an in-memory HDFStore! http://pytables.github.io/cookbook/inmemory_hdf5_files.html (you just need to pass in the addl driver arguments to HDFStore and this will work)

Comment: This is an excellent use case for `DataFrame.query()` and `DataFrame.eval()`. Please try it out and let us know how it goes!

Comment: Make sure to also use the Cythonized "&" and "||" operators. EG: df[(df['A'] == 1) & (df['B'] == 2) & (df['C'] == 3)]. These operators are much faster than using "and" and "or".

Answer (score 1):

I would try something in this flavor:

Suppose you have the following dataframe

```
N = 10000000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':np.random.binomial(1,0.5,N),
    'B':np.random.binomial(2,0.5,N),
    'nume1':np.random.uniform(0,1,N),
    'nume2':np.random.normal(0,1,N)})
```

then doing this

```
tmp = df[['A','B','nume1','nume2']].query('A > 0.5').groupby('B').sum().reset_index()[['B','nume1','nume2']]
```

is the SQL equivalent of

```
select B, sum(nume1),sum(nume2)
from df
where A > 0.5
group by B
```

this takes a little less then a sec (926ms, using %timeit) on my moderate (i7 quad-core, 16GB ram) machine.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details it's hard to answer your question.

You should indeed build an index of your conditional columns.

```
df['idx'] = (df['col1'] * df['col2']) ** (df['col3'] + df['col4']) * df['col5'] == 0.012
df = df.set_index('idx')
```

Rewriting your condition to an indexable column may be hard.
Keep in mind you can set all the columns as the index

```
df = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5' ...])
```

This documentation on advanced indexing in Pandas may help you think about your problem:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax